# Why does the output of this file put the comma before the text starts?

Tags: php, text

```
<?php

$lines = file('brand_list.txt');

$hi = ",";
foreach ($lines as $line) {
     $xml .=  "$line" . "$hi";
}


file_put_contents('brand-list-url.txt', $xml);
```

**brand-list-url.txt**

,Pioneer 
,Kenwood 
,JVC 
,Sony 
,Clarion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the first line of the `brand_list.txt` is probably a blank line and `$line` contains the newline.

Read the docs on [`file()`](http://php.net/file). I'd also encourage you to look at [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode).

Answer (score 1):

The $line variable contains a newline so the comma appears on the next line in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `$line` contains the `\n` (newline) character.

You'll want to `rtrim()` the `$line` and then append the `\n` back.